# How do I remove padding inside a MenuButton?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI project targetting MacOS 11.6 Catalina. I include a view with a menu:

```swift
MenuButton("☰") {
    Button("Stuff …") {

    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    .background(Color(.blue))
}
```

No I can’t find any documentation on `MenuButton` whatsoever, and I only came across it by accident. I seems to do the job, but I want to customise the buttons inside.

The problem is that the menu appears to have some sort of inner padding:

[image]

If I add `.padding(0)` to the button or to the menu, it doesn’t help.

How can I remove the menu padding?

Comment: What padding do you mean? Could you provide screenshot? Did you compare it with other system menu, maybe it is just system behavior (space for marks to be aligned)?

Comment: @Asperi I have added the image

Comment: Just remove `frame(maxWidth: .infinity)` and you will get default popup button items layout. Actually I don't understand what do you try to do with that frame and background.

Comment: @Asperi I am trying to implement a background change on hover. The code does the job, but the background never fills the width. The `.frame()` widens the button, but still doesn’t fill the width of the menu, the way that a normal menu behaves. This is part of a workaround for some quirky behaviour with `MenuButton` (as well as with `Picker`) when Reduce transparency is turned on. If I can get a solution to this question, the rest will be fine.